# Multiple logins on the same website

Tags: authentication

If a hacker uses MITM in an open WiFi network, he can easily grab plaintext passwords so that he can login from his PC and change it. Is there any solution for this?

I wonder when we log in to websites, why are they allowing multiple logins for the same account at once? Isn't it a security flaw? Logging into the same account if a user in the account is still active, why are website designers not concerned about it?

Comment: Some people are legitimately logged in in more than one place at the same time. For example, on laptop and on smartphone, or on desktop and on tablet.

Answer (score 3):

They fixed it when they implemented transport layer security, it provides end-to-end encryption (and authentication) between the browser and the webserver.  So, even though a "hacker" could intercept your traffic, it will be encrypted and stealing your credentials is a lot harder.  If the "bank site" doesn't use transport layer security, then that's a very poor practice.

Some systems prevent multiple logins from the same account, but that could also result in a "Denial of Service":

- Do you prevent new sessions from being created
- Do you break off the original session.

Either way, you could kick out the legitimate user.  Plus, one could be legitimately logged in from several locations (home, work and mobile).

Comment: In order to avoid misunderstandings, I recommend using the term "transport layer protection" instead of SSL. SSL is considered not secure, as security professionals I think we should talk about TLS or transport layer protection.

Comment: @m1ke FYI, I edited the question in such a way as to remove the bit about http, because it didn't seem like the core of the question. That means the first part of your answer lost context.